# Autodetecting Oracle data types

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

I'm trying to fetch data from multiple tables from an Oracle db and insert it into a sql db. The problem that I am running into is that I am fetching almost 50 columns of data all of different datatypes. I then proceed to insert these individual column values into a SQL statement which then inserts the data into the sql db. So the algo looks something like this:

```
Fetch row data{
 create a variable for each individual column value ( int value = reader.getInt32(0); )
 add a sqlparameter for it (command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("value", value)); )
 once all the 50 or so variables have been created make a sql statement
 Insert into asdf values (value,........)
}
```

Doing it this way for a table with <10 columns seems ok but when it exceeds that length this process seems tedious and extraneous. I was wondering if there was a simpler way of doing this like fetch row data and automatically determine column data type and automatically create a varialbe and automatically insert into sql statement. I would appreciate it if anyone could direct me to the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data reader has a neutral `GetValue` method returning an `object` and the `SqlCommand` has an `AddWithValue` method that does not require to specify a parameter type.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < reader.VisibleFieldCount; i++) {
    object value = reader.GetValue(i);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + i, value);
}
```

You could also create the SQL command automatically

```cs
var columns = new StringBuilder();
var values = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < reader.VisibleFieldCount; i++) {
    values.Append("@").Append(i).Append(", ");
    columns.Append("[").Append(reader.GetName(i)).Append("], ");
}
values.Length -= 2;    // Remove last ", "
columns.Length -= 2;
string insert = String.Format("INSERT INTO myTable ({0}) VALUES ({1})",
                              columns.ToString(), values.ToString());
```